# Change Code theme color

Tags: code, color

Is there a way to change the code app black background color to be equal to terminal color to get a cool integration? Look at the image for a better understanding.

Thank you in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: edit `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/solarized-dark.xml` and customize it the way you want. For example, line 29, changing the value of 'base3' from #002B36 to #2B2B2B will get you the desired background color.

[image]

Long answer: take a look at [Dark theme on Elemntary Code instead of “Solar Dark”](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21540/dark-theme-on-elemntary-code-instead-of-solar-dark)

Comment: I changed line 29 as you said, but nothing happened. I use the gsettings command, as you said on the another questions, restart and nothing happened too. What do you think?

Comment: Did you restart Code after changing solarized-dark.xml file?

Comment: It now works quite well! Thank you!

Taking advantage of your goodwill, how a change the vertical line color where is the line number? Another question, is there a way to set a transparency when Code is minimized as on Terminal?

Thank you, you rock!

Comment: I think that I found it the line color, so remain just the transparency tricky :).

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by ' set a transparency when Code is minimized'?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the Terminal's background, then you need to install the Elementary Tweaks and go to Terminal menu —> Background Color and change the background color, you can also change the background transparency.

Also, I don't recommend changing the background color from gray to any other color or setting the transparency too high. In my opinion it doesn't look neat, but you can do whatever you want!

Comment: I mean let the code background like the terminal background when the terminal is minimized. Did you get it?

Comment: @Diego Magela if I understand correctly, you want to make Code's background color transparent as Terminal look when it's minimized? If so, I don't think that Code supports this feature, but I could be wrong, because I don't even use this application. In other hand you could set Terminal always non-transparent using the same method that I posted to make Terminal and Code look the same.

Answer (score 0):

@VladPop, here is the transparency I mean.

[image]